# unable to read from the env file in the ts file

Tags: environment-variables, nestjs

I have written the following code:

`app.module.ts`

```
const dotenv = require('dotenv');

dotenv.config();

@Module({
  imports: [ConfigModule.forRoot({isGlobal: true}),TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
    migrations: [migrationPath],
    entities: [Users],
  }),AuthModule],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

I deleted the database connectivity because its irrelevant to the question, but its just there.

`auth.module.ts`

```
@Module({  
  imports: [    
      ConfigModule.forRoot(), 

      JwtModule.register({
          secret: process.env.SECRETKEY,
           signOptions: {
              expiresIn:process.env.EXPIRESIN,
          },
      }),
  ], 

})
export class AuthModule {}
```

My system does not read the value of the `SECRETKEY`, I have tried many solutions online but none is working.
Instead, I get the `unable to connect to database error`.
PS: I just omitted the db configurations from the question but in the code, they are there and works fine only makes a problem when I add the `configuration module` code in the `auth.module.ts`

Comment: if you use dotenv, why do you need ConfigModule again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My working example auth.module.ts:

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
import { LocalStrategy } from './local.strategy';
import { PassportModule } from '@nestjs/passport';
import { AuthController } from './auth.controller';
import { JwtModule } from '@nestjs/jwt';
import { jwtConstants } from './constants';
import { JwtStrategy } from './jwt.strategy';
import { UserModule } from '../entities/user/user.module';
import { ConfigModule, ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';

@Module({
  imports:[
    PassportModule.register({ defaultStrategy: 'jwt' }),
    UserModule,
    JwtModule.registerAsync({
      imports: [ConfigModule],
      useFactory: async (configService: ConfigService) => ({
        secret: configService.get<string>('SECRET_KEY'),
        expiresIn: configService.get<number>('EXPIRES_IN')
      }),
      inject: [ConfigService],
    }),
  ],
  controllers: [
    AuthController
  ],
  providers: [
    AuthService,
    LocalStrategy,
    JwtStrategy,
    ConfigService
  ],
  exports: [
    AuthService
  ],
})
export class AuthModule {}
```

.env

```
DATABASE_USER=*********
DATABASE_PASS=********
DATABASE_HOST=*********
DATABASE_NAME=******
DATABASE_PORT=********
SECRET_KEY=************************
EXPIRES_IN=3600
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `ConfigModule.forRoot()` from `AuthModule`.

`ConfigModule.forRoot()` will make the `env` variables only available in the feature module(AuthModule).

Usually `ConfigModule.forRoot()` is only called once at `AppModule` and other modules just import it, for example:

```js
@Module({  
  imports: [    
      ConfigModule, 

      JwtModule.register({
          secret: process.env.SECRETKEY,
           signOptions: {
              expiresIn:process.env.EXPIRESIN,
          },
      }),
  ], 

})
```

You already made the env variables available globally by importing the `ConfigModule` with `isGlobal: true` so you don't need to import `ConfigModule` in the `AuthModule`.

Check the doc here - https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/configuration

**Note:**

The `ConfigModule` already uses `dotenv` internally so you don't need use `dotenv` in your `AppModule`

Comment: I tried this way. now it doesn't show error but I am still unable to get the value. Maybe if you can help me reading the value with the dotenv?

Comment: you can just remove all ConfigModule imports if dotenv is still being used :)